# Random GMail background image

Tags: gmail, gmail-themes

I'm getting a little tired of the same old GMail themes from "random". GMail lets you use your own background image by giving it a url.  Is is possible to give it a url that changes every once in a while, giving a much wider range of themes?  If the answer is yes, what is a source of such a thing. I was thinking something like Flickr would be a good source, but I couldn't find anywhere that had an image url that changed on a regular basis.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User%3aDuesentrieb/POTD) might do what you want. It calls various-sized images from Wikimedia sites using a stable URL. They might not be the prettiest sometimes, but could be worth a try.

Comment: This will at least tell me if it works, but Wikipedia PODs are not generally amenable to GMail backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Andrew Lott's answer, I've found the following URL works really well:

http://tools.wikimedia.de/~daniel/potd/potd.php/commons/1600x1200

Note that changing the dimensions at the end of the URL resizes the image - so the above returns a picture 1600px wide by 1200px high. Set it to your monitor's pixel width & height for best results.

Comment: Seems that I may have spoken too soon - for the past week the page consistently gives an error about the SQL connection pool being empty... Maybe we flooded his little server with requests?

Answer (score 0):

In Gmail's settings under 'Themes', you can pick the theme 'Random', which will apply a random theme **daily**.

See [this blog post](http://googlesystem.blogspot.be/2009/09/random-gmail-theme.html) on Google System from 2009.

I don't think it's possibly to shuffle only the background image.

Comment: I know you can do random. See the first sentence of my question.

Comment: Now it seems to be down. So I need a new test url.